# Get Total Count from Current Status Query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, relational-database

I have problem to count total data on current status on mysql query.

Briefly, i have 3 tables that relate each other.

```
m_shift_schedule     site_shift_schedule      m_ticket
================     ===================     ============
* shift_id   ======>  * shift_id             * ticket_id
* start_time          * shift_date           * ticket_status
* end_time            * user_id   ========>  * ticket_served_by
```

My current query:

```
SELECT user_id,
  case when count(m_ticket.ticket_served_by)<2 then 'idle' 
     when count(m_ticket.ticket_served_by)=2 then 'Busy' 
     when count(m_ticket.ticket_served_by)>2 then 'Overload' end as status
FROM site_shift_schedule
LEFT JOIN m_shift_schedule ON site_shift_schedule.shift_id = m_shift_schedule.shift_id
LEFT JOIN m_ticket ON site_shift_schedule.user_id=m_ticket.ticket_served_by
   WHERE site_shift_schedule.shift_date =  '2019-02-11' and m_ticket.ticket_status in (4,5,6)
group by user_id
```

My output from query above:

```
 user_id                           Status
 =============================   ============
 ismail.rahman.saanin@random.co     Idle
 lutfi.aldi.nugroho@random.co       Busy
 tb.makkiy@yihuu.co                 Overload
```

And the question, What should i do if i want show the output become like this:

```
Idle                 1
Busy                 1
Overload             1
```

Thanks guys...

Answer (score 0):

Use the sub-query to get this as following:

```
SELECT status,count(user_id) as count from (
SELECT user_id,
  case when count(m_ticket.ticket_served_by)<2 then 'idle' 
     when count(m_ticket.ticket_served_by)=2 then 'Busy' 
     when count(m_ticket.ticket_served_by)>2 then 'Overload' end as status
FROM site_shift_schedule
LEFT JOIN m_shift_schedule ON site_shift_schedule.shift_id = m_shift_schedule.shift_id
LEFT JOIN m_ticket ON site_shift_schedule.user_id=m_ticket.ticket_served_by
   WHERE site_shift_schedule.shift_date =  '2019-02-11' and m_ticket.ticket_status in (4,5,6)
group by user_id)
group by status
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple option would be to just wrap your current aggregation query and then aggregate by the `status` computed column:

```
SELECT
    t.status,
    COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM
(
    SELECT user_id,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(mt.ticket_served_by) < 2 THEN 'idle' 
            WHEN COUNT(mt.ticket_served_by) = 2 THEN 'Busy' 
            WHEN COUNT(mt.ticket_served_by) > 2 THEN 'Overload' END AS status
    FROM site_shift_schedule ss
    LEFT JOIN m_shift_schedule ms ON ss.shift_id = ms.shift_id
    LEFT JOIN m_ticket mt ON ss.user_id = mt.ticket_served_by
    WHERE ss.shift_date = '2019-02-11' AND mt.ticket_status in (4,5,6)
    GROUP BY user_id
) t
GROUP BY
    t.status;
```

Note that I introduced table aliases into the query to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should fix your query so it counts the "0" rows:

```
SELECT user_id,
       (case when count(t.ticket_served_by) < 2 then 'idle' 
             when count(t.ticket_served_by) = 2 then 'Busy' 
             when count(t.ticket_served_by) > 2 then 'Overload'
        end) as status
FROM site_shift_schedule sss LEFT JOIN 
     m_shift_schedule ss
     ON sss.shift_id = ss.shift_id LEFT JOIN
     m_ticket t
     ON t.ticket_served_by = sss.user_id AND
        t.ticket_status in (4, 5, 6)
WHERE sss.shift_date = '2019-02-11' 
GROUP BY user_id;
```

Otherwise, your `WHERE` turns the outer join to a left join.

With this, you can get what you want with an additional level of aggregation:

```
SELECT status, count(*)
FROM (SELECT user_id,
             (case when count(t.ticket_served_by) < 2 then 'idle' 
                   when count(t.ticket_served_by) = 2 then 'Busy' 
                   when count(t.ticket_served_by) > 2 then 'Overload'
              end) as status
      FROM site_shift_schedule sss LEFT JOIN 
           m_shift_schedule ss
           ON sss.shift_id = ss.shift_id LEFT JOIN
           m_ticket t
           ON t.ticket_served_by = sss.user_id AND
              t.ticket_status in (4, 5, 6)
      WHERE sss.shift_date = '2019-02-11' 
      GROUP BY user_id
     ) s
GROUP BY status;
```

Comment: what does it means with t in LEFT JOIN
           m_ticket t
           ON t.ticket_served_by = sss.user_id AND
              t.ticket_status in (4, 5, 6), cause in case when count(t.ticket_served_by) already being used t

Comment: @aldi . . . `t` is a table alias.  It is a very basic part of SQL.